# Should multi-unit files be named with lower camel case?

Tags: scala

According to Scala style guide (https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/files.html), multi-unit files should be named with lower camel case. However, nobody seems to do it. I asked few experienced Scala developers and they didn't know about this convention. Even mentioned example is misleading and `Option.scala` (checked for scala 2.13.6) starts with capital letter.

This whole idea is for me rather obscure. On one hand official style guide states that as

> very important convention

on the other hand even files built-in Scala language don't follow this convention.

Comment: This is really an "opinion-based" question and is likely to get closed, but the answer would appear to be "No". I use the name of the primary class or object in the file, with upper camel case.

Comment: De facto if the convention is not applied by anyone, it's not anymore a convention. I've very rarely seen it used.

Comment: I have used lowercase named files that contain many things. However, what I have done in those cases is having an object that emulates a package which is named like the file.